# A subquery within a CASE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm trying to put a subquery within a CASE statement. The subquery itself is working fine, but if I put it in another code it can't process. What can I do best to solve?

```
CASE WHEN dbo.T1.TYPE = 0 
THEN dbo.Data.QTY * dbo.Data.SALESPRICE 
ELSE 
     CASE WHEN dbo.T1.TYPE = 1 
     THEN dbo.Data.QTY * 
          (
          SELECT        dbo.Data.ID, 
               CASE WHEN SUM(dbo.Data.QTY) = 0 
               THEN SUM(dbo.Data.SALESPRICE) 
               ELSE SUM(dbo.Data.SALESPRICE) / SUM(dbo.Data.QTY) 
               END AS REVph
          FROM  dbo.Data LEFT OUTER JOIN
               dbo.T1ON dbo.Data.ID = dbo.T1.ID
          WHERE         (dbo.T1.TYPE = 1)
          GROUP BY  dbo.Data.ID
         ) 
ELSE 0 
END 
END
```

Comment: I think you need to join that subquery on the data, then in your "THEN" do "dbo.Data.QTY * REVph". As of now, its trying to multiply a single number by an entire table!

Comment: It seems to me that the sub-query isn't scalar.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help us to help you.

Comment: "it can't process" - maybe you could be more specific. Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? A `CASE` _expression_ is not a statement - it must return exactly one value. Your subquery returns multiple columns and I also don't see how you're preventing it from returning multiple rows either.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a subquery in a context where a single value is allowed.  Such a subquery is called a *scalar subquery*.

However, the subquery is returning more than one column.  That is not allowed.  A scalar subquery can only return one column and at most one row.

Your question is rather unclear on what you want to accomplish, so I can only explain the problem that you are having.

Comment: This already helps a lot, because I understand my problem. My problem is, depending on the outcome of the first columnin my subquery, it should basically take the value from the CASE statement in the subquery (second column). So basically I need a LEFT JOIN here, but I think the only way to achieve this, is to not make a subquery, but just a completly seperate query and then join them.

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @TomDamkot . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.